# SEVERE: Context [/SpringMVCPractice1] startup failed due to previous errors

Tags: spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, tomcat7

I am practicing Spring MVC web application (Spring4) using Java config files rather than XML config files. the Tomcat Server is not able to start the web application. during starting Tomcat I've received the following error in the console , but there is not previous message on the console

SEVERE: Context [/SpringMVCPractice1] startup failed due to previous errors

I don't have web.xml file and dispatcher-servlet.xml as it is java file config

here are whole log from console and whole source code

Reference of practice : Spring in Action, 4th Edition: Covers Spring 4

Log:

```
Mar 05, 2015 4:59:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe;C:\apache-maven-3.2.3\bin;.
Mar 05, 2015 4:59:42 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringMVCPractice1' did not find a matching property.
Mar 05, 2015 4:59:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 05, 2015 4:59:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 05, 2015 4:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1234 ms
Mar 05, 2015 4:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 05, 2015 4:59:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
Mar 05, 2015 4:59:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/SpringMVCPractice1] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 05, 2015 4:59:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 05, 2015 4:59:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 05, 2015 4:59:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4073 ms
```

WebConfig.java :

```
package spittr.config; 
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration; 
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc; 
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration 
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("spitter.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling( DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
    }



}
```

SpittrWebAppInitializer.java :

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer ;

public class SpittrWebAppInitializer
                  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
   @Override
   protected String[] getServletMappings(){
      return new String[] { "/" };
   }

  @Override 
  protected Class[] getRootConfigClasses() {
      return new Class<?>[]  { RootConfig.class };
  }

   @Override
   protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses(){ 
      return new Class<?>[] { WebConfig.class };
   }
}
```

RootConfig.java :

```
package spittr.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "spitter" }, excludeFilters = { @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = EnableWebMvc.class) })
public class RootConfig {
}
```

HomeController.java :

```
package spittr.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
//import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import static  org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.*;

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = GET)
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

Under folder ...\WEB-INF\views\
home.jsp :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> 
<%@ page session="false" %> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Spittr</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
          type="text/css" 
          href="<c:url value="/resources/style.css" />" > 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <h1>Welcome to Spittr</h1> 
    <a href="<c:url value="/spittles" />">Spittles</a> | 
    <a href="<c:url value="/spitter/register" />">Register</a> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Try to take a look to the extended log files (`/var/log/tomcat7/...`)

Comment: Is that really the entire log from the console? I'm, thinking there should be another entry for SEVERE. Clear the console and restart. Make sure your eclipse console buffer is large enough to not loose any lines written to the console.

Comment: I increased Console buffer; there is not more log than what I already posted. thanks